# OpAmp clamping circuit not working for a Pulse voltage reference in PSpice

Tags: operational-amplifier, pspice, diode-clamp

So, we had an analog electronics lab exam today where we had to generate a waveform:[image]

I wrote the PSpice code, using a clamper circuit (in hindsight a summer was the best option, but whatever). The code is as:

```
VSP 7 0 DC 50
VSN 8 0 DC -50
VNO 2 6 DC 0
R1 2 3 4.7k
C1 2 1 0.1u
VI 1 0 SIN(0 -8 10)
D1 5 6 D1N4002
VREF 4 0 PULSE(-48 -8 0 0 0 100M 200M)
XA 4 3 7 8 5 UA741
.lib nom.lib
.TRAN 10u 500m 100M
.probe
.end
```

[image]

The problem is that code is not working an I can't figure out why.
If I give replace VREF from a pulse to:

```
VREF 4 0 DC -48
or
VREF 4 0 DC -8
```

the sine wave gets clamped to -48V or -8V. But when I give a pulse it doesn't. I am getting an output waveform as 
[image]

Can someone please help me figure out the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Your waveform is the sum of a sine (period 100ms, amplitude 8V) and a square (100ms at -40V, then 100ms at 0V).

Since the question is to generate this waveform in spice, I'd just put these two sources in series to sum the voltages and be done with it... no need for any opamp.

Comment: My question is not about adding these 2 sources, which I know will work, but about why the circuit which I have designed will not work, i.e why is it not clamping

Comment: Well, you should edit the question to make this clear, also at which voltage would you like it to clamp, etc. You can try the built-in schematic editor on this website to enter your schematic, it also comes with a free simulator.

Comment: The question is clear. It mentions that the clamping circuit is not working for a pulse reference voltage. In the details I have mentioned that it clamps for -48V DC and -8V DC, but not for a pulse of -48V to -8V. I think you should try reading the question again.

Answer (score 0):

The circuit cannot work with a DC Vref as the diode only conducts when Vin>Vref, (which in this case are both negative). So it only works when sin crosses 0 with a pulsed clamp to 0V. In order to create this you can detect the peak of a 90 deg phase shifted input for a 1 shot of Ron*C=1/f*100 or so to shift the cap voltage.

TVs analog do this active clamp on trailing sync pulse back porch but takes several pulse to restore back porch to 0V so in one shot, it takes a low RC value which is why I suggested f*100 Hz ...100Hz*100 ..=10kHz or 100us or less.

A 90 deg phase shift can be done with 2 stage 45 deg HPF or all pass filter then compare peak stored to input with small hysteresis. Or perhaps max dV/dt detect on input for  offset zero crossing using 2nd order dv/dt in sampled data of signal . Then each sample on 2nd order derivativeyou clamp input cap to 0V at that output zero crossing for 1 quantization sample.

Does this make any sense?

Comment: I didn't get what you are saying. The problem is that when I give a reference of -48V the sine wave gets clamped. When I give a reference of -8V it gets clamped. However, when I give a pulse of -48 to -8V it is not clamping to the voltages alternately. It is only clamping to the -8V period of the pulse and not the -48V period. Why is that happening?

Comment: Its not clear to me what you are trying to do either.  You were asked to generte a waveform and you instead implemented a negative peak clamp which cannot shift at the sine zero crossing.  . your -48Vref pulse input  seems to "clip" the sine at -8v for some reason, or Igues that is just quantization error in your samples.  But the concept is flawed , sorry I cant explain why it does not work as you expect.